# Python: Series encoded as a string

Tags: python, string, series

my problem is quite simple.

I have a series that is encoded as a string ('series_as_string' in my code) and I want to have it as a series of floats ('series_as_series').

I have already tried some options: read the Series with pd.Series, save it and read it with pd.read_csv(), ... I wanted to parse the string and encoded it as a list but I didn't find an efficient way to do it...

```
series_as_string = """0      0.7070
1      1.4332
2      2.1882
3      2.9695
4      3.7748

Length: 5, dtype: float64"""

series_as_series = pd.Series([0.7070, 1.4332, 2.1882, 2.9695, 3.7748])
```

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: how did you end up with `series_as_string` in the first place? It's a str representation of `pandas.Series`. i.e. this looks like XY problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can read_csv with io module

```
import io
series_as_string = """0      0.7070
1      1.4332
2      2.1882
3      2.9695
4      3.7748

Length: 5, dtype: float64"""
fixed_string = '\n'.join(series_as_string.split('\n')[:-2])
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(fixed_string),sep='\s+',header=None)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    0   1
0   0   0.7070
1   1   1.4332
2   2   2.1882
3   3   2.9695
4   4   3.7748
```

if you want specifically Series:

```
sr = df.iloc[:,1]
sr = 
0    0.7070
1    1.4332
2    2.1882
3    2.9695
4    3.7748
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```